# MongoDB in docker: pass variable to script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker, variables

Need help with right syntax for the next command:

```
sudo docker exec wekan-db sh -c 'mongo -u {{ admin_user }} -p {{ mongo_password }} --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'var ID_draft_user='{{ user_hash.stdout }}'' /data/mongo_info_user.js'
```

MongoDB is running inside docker container. The command above is used in ansible playbook (shell module) and the **user_hash** value is registered during one of the tasks.

The problem is no matter what way I am trying to pass the **user_hash.stdout** varibale, I get:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("29aebb5d-5e0f-4aa4-b40a-7ef4f6cf323a") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.2
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing variable name :
@(shell eval):1:3
exiting with code -4
```

Suppose there should be one more step in passing variable, but not so familiar with js, so maybe someone can give me clear explanation about what is wrong here.

The js script is for example:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('test')
db.users.find({ _id: ID_draft_user }).pretty()
```

Comment: There's a [`mongodb_shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mongodb/mongodb_shell_module.html); using that (targeting the published port of your database container) might be easier than trying to do the same thing via a shell command.

Comment: Not sure. I have to pass variable anyway, but if I use that module with both eval and file it turns into
`parameters are mutually exclusive: eval|file`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in my situation there was two simple ways to solve it:

1. to create separate js script with variables, and upload it once I have registered facts I need
2. to create separate js script and just use "replace" to set up needed values.

In both ways script was uploaded to container and than I just run it via ansible using `docker exec`